# Symfony and Doctrine using setParameters make result set empty

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I can't understand why I have different results with this code:

The only thing I change token for setParameter.

The result is empty.

This works

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('t')
->select('t, c')
->leftJoin('t.documentos', 'c')
->where('t.flagStatus = :status')
->andWhere('c.flagStatus = :status')
->andWhere('t.idSecretaria in (:s)')
->andWhere('t.typedoc = 1')
->orderBy('c.tituloInformacao', 'ASC')
->setParameters([
    'status' => true,
    's' => 8,
])
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

But this won't work an empty result set is given.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('t')
->select('t, c')
->leftJoin('t.documentos', 'c')
->where('t.flagStatus = :status')
->andWhere('c.flagStatus = :status')
->andWhere('t.idSecretaria in (:s)')
->andWhere('t.typedoc = :td')
->orderBy('c.tituloInformacao', 'ASC')
->setParameters([
    'status' => true,
    's' => 8,
    'td' => 1,
])
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

Comment: Nothing obvious jumps out.  Maybe check your debug toolbar and compare the generated sql.  I assume that your twig templates and what not remain exactly the same?

Comment: Twig still the same.. Also I am dump results.. Now I'll try compare debug toolbar generated query as you indicated. thank you.

Comment: You know what is crazy about this? There are no differences in toolbar and if I copy and paste runnable query in Oracle SQL editor the query executes and returns data.

Comment: Might be something to do with types.  Add ['boolean','integer','integer'] as a second argument to setParameter.  Older versions used to have a problem with using the same key (:status) more than once.  So you could also try cstatus and tstatus.  Just guessing.  Might be oracle specific.  Maybe double check your database column types.